# Where to find IndexedDB in Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have this problem that I cannot open the page anymore since I already reach the max limit
capacity of my indexeddb but I wanted to copy it so that I can migrate it to another device.

My question is where can I locate the path of the IndexedDB Folder in Android? I know in Windows
it would be easy to find `%appdata%/local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/IndexedDb`.
However in android no idea where to find it.

Hopefully someone can answer my question, and hopefully no need of 'ROOT'

Thanks.

Comment: The path you have included in your post is for Windows not Android. If there is an IndexedDb on Android it will be located on most devices somewhere below `/data/data/com.android.chrome/` which is only accessible with root permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The path you have included in your post is for Windows not Android.

## General approach how to access app data without root

If there is an IndexedDb on Android it will be located on most devices somewhere below `/data/data/com.android.chrome/` which is only accessible with root permissions.

However the Chrome app allows backup via adb, therefore you should be able to make an backup of the chrome app data and extract the file then from the backup. For doing so you need a device with activated developer options and enabled Android Debug Bridge (adb).

Backup Chrome data to the file `backup.ab`

```
adb backup com.android.chrome
```

Then you need to convert the backup using [Android backup Extractor (abe)](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/releases):

```
java -jar abe-all.jar unpack backup.ab backup.tar
```

Now you can open the created `backup.tar` file using an archive tool like 7zip an extract everything or just search for the file `IndexedDb` file.

If you have found the file and you want to modify it the whole process works in the opposite direction, using "abe pack mode" and "adb resore".

## Chrome and IndexedDB

Looking at the data structures created by the latest Chrome app on a rooted DB there is no `IndexedDB` file created by Chrome on Android.

Instead `IndexedDB` is a directory containing multiple database - one for every web site. Each database consists of multiple files.
Therefore if you expect that a certain site has created a very large IndexedDB storage it should be possible to reclaim that storage by deleting the IndexedDB storage of that site.

You can display details on the IndexedDB by opening the url `chrome://indexeddb-internals/` in Chrome.

Comment: woah, it works for the other apps. however when i tried it in com.android.chrome it has 1kb file without anything inside of it. sad :( but thank you for the answer.

Comment: @user2180795 That is really strange, backup should be allowed for Chrome according to it's AndroidManifest.xml. But when I test the command on a device I also only get a 47bytes file. I am not sure why this happens.

Comment: I think I have to find another way to downsize the existing indexeddb code, via updating the data on it when the page loads like down sizing the base64 files added to the indexeddb. Since backup without rooting is not possible. :(

Comment: See my update. By using the url chrome://indexeddb-internals/ you can see how much data is really occupied by the IndexedDB structures in your web browser.

Comment: Woah, it almost got it problem is that when I tried to download the data it says 'Insufficient Permissions' :(